# Javascript - Chrome extension - Webrequest - Responsebody

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, webrequest

I want to write an extension for Chrome to watch my XHR calls and I found that i have to use webRequest for this.

I want to get the response-body of the request but i never can find how to do this. Is this possible?

```
// chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
    var callback = function(details) {
        var url = details.url;

        console.log(details);
    };

    var filter = {
        urls: ["*://safan.dev/*"]
    };

    var ops = ["requestBody"];

    chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
        callback, filter, ops
    );
// });
```

And manifest:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Forge of Empires",
  "description": "FOE",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "webRequest",
    "<all_urls>"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["logic.js"]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I want to get the response-body of the request but i never can find how to do this. Is this possible?

Not at the moment. There is a [long-standing feature request](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=487422).

---

Note that you can do it using [`devtools.network` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools_network) (requires Dev Tools to be open) or [Debugger API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/debugger) (requires Dev Tools to be closed, low-level).

Comment: Note that using the Debugger API will lead to a large warning banner in Chrome stating "'{Your extension name}' is debugging the browser [Cancel]".